# Is there a way to convert a date varchar string with a different date format to MySQL date format?

Tags: mysql, regex, date, timestamp

We imported a table, most probably from an Excel file, where a DATETIME, saved in a varchar, has a format that looks like this:

```
12/06/2003 07:42
```

Is there any way to convert that into a valid MySQL date format for later convert the field from varchar to DATETIME? Maybe with a regular expression? Note that 12 is the day and 06 the month.

```
2003-06-12 07:42:00
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use str_to_date for this:

```
select str_to_date('12/06/2003 07:42','%d/%m/%Y %H:%i')
```